# How to use Graphene GraphQL framework with Django REST Framework authentication

Tags: python, django, rest, authentication, graphql

I got some REST API endpoints in Django and I'd like to use [the same authentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/) for Graphene. The [documentation](http://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/) does not provide any guidance.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For example, if you are using `authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)` in your API views, you could add an endpoint to a GraphQLView decorated in this way:

**urls.py:**

```
# ...
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.decorators import authentication_classes, permission_classes, api_view

def graphql_token_view():
    view = GraphQLView.as_view(schema=schema)
    view = permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))(view)
    view = authentication_classes((TokenAuthentication,))(view)
    view = api_view(['GET', 'POST'])(view)
    return view

urlpatterns = [
# ...
    url(r'^graphql_token', graphql_token_view()),
    url(r'^graphql', csrf_exempt(GraphQLView.as_view(schema=schema))),
    url(r'^graphiql', include('django_graphiql.urls')),
# ...
```

Note that we added a new `^graphql_token` endpoint and kept the original `^graphql` which is used by the GraphiQL tool.

Then, you should set the `Authorization` header in your GraphQL client and point to the `graphql_token` endpoint.

---

UPDATE: See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/issues/249) where people have suggested alternative solutions and full working examples.

Comment: Does this still work for you? I am trying to do the same with SessionAuthentication but I get an error back from graphene-django when it tries to read the body of the request?

Comment: Still works, but I haven't the most up-to-date versions of packages. My answer used:
Django==1.8.3
djangorestframework==3.2.2
django-graphiql==0.4.4
graphene==0.10.2
graphql-core==0.5.3
graphql-django-view==1.3
graphql-relay==0.4.4

Comment: is it possible to do a post request ?

Comment: @KentDelaCruzFueconcillo Yes.

Comment: Can you further explain what this means?

Note that we added a new ^graphql_token endpoint and kept the original ^graphql which is used by the GraphiQL tool.

Why do you have 2 seperate endpoints?

Answer (score 3):

Adding some additional steps that I had to take when following this integration:

```py
class RTGraphQLView(GraphQLView):

def parse_body(self, request):
    if type(request) is rest_framework.request.Request:
        return request.data
    return super().parse_body(request)
```

Graphene was expecting the `.body` attr but DRF reads it and attaches it to `.data` before being passed to GraphQLView.