# How to restrict anonymous users from GraphQL API endpoint?

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, graphql, graphene-python

Django has two approaches.

1. Regular DRF restricts user on Middleware level. So not logged in user doesn't reach anything.
2. GraphQL, on contrary, uses "per method" approach. So middleware passes all the request and each method. But afterward method calls decorator.

I want to implement 1st approach but for GraphQL. But in that case I need to open path for login mutation. How can I extract mutation name from payload?

Comment: Are you really asking how to restrict users not logged in from reaching the API?

Comment: Yes. And I want to do it once. Otherwise if I forget next time to add decorator to function - it will be breach.

Comment: I found this answer helpful as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39026831/how-to-use-graphene-graphql-framework-with-django-rest-framework-authentication/39026832#39026832

Answer (score 8):

If you want restrict a GraphQL API endpoint to Django logged in users, you can do it by extending GraphQLView with `LoginRequiredMixin`

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from graphene_django.views import GraphQLView

class PrivateGraphQLView(LoginRequiredMixin, GraphQLView):
    """Adds a login requirement to graphQL API access via main endpoint."""
    pass
```

and then adding this view to your `urls.py` like

```
path('api/', PrivateGraphQLView.as_view(schema=schema), name='api')
```

in the usual way as per the [docs](http://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/tutorial-plain/#creating-graphql-and-graphiql-views).

If you don't want to protect your entire API, you can create another schema and endpoint for the unprotected queries and mutations, which allows a clear separation between each.  For example in urls.py:

```
path('public_api/', GraphQLView.as_view(schema=public_schema), name='public_api')
```

Note that every API endpoint must have at least one query to work or it will cause an assertion error.

Comment: Thank you. But if I need to pass some calls without authentication? login mutation, for example?

Comment: It's possible to have a different API endpoint URL that doesn't require authentication.  One advantage this approach is that allows you to keep a clear separation.  I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it serves your purpose, but I've used the following library which used JWT authentication with graphene similar to how JWT with DRF works!

https://github.com/flavors/django-graphql-jwt

Comment: Is there a way to wrap _all_ routes with a login decorator (except for auth endpoints)?