# How do I reference multiple schema files in Graphene Django project settings for access in graphql?

Tags: python, django, graphql, graphene-django

I got a Django project with two apps. The project uses graphene-django. Each of the apps got their own schema.py file. How do i reference both the schema files in settings.py in the project folder so that I can access all the schema's in graphql?

I have tried:

```
GRAPHENE = {
    "SCHEMA": 
        "blog.schema.schema",
        "newsletter.schema.schema",
```

```
GRAPHENE = {
    "SCHEMA":[
        "blog.schema.schema",
        "newsletter.schema.schema",
    ],
```

...and other combinations which I can't remember, but they all either lead to errors or to just the last schema in the list to work.

Comment: I have an old example of creating two different schemas in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51116456/how-to-restrict-anonymous-users-from-graphql-api-endpoint/51213510#51213510 -- the trick is to edit the urls.py file.  Hopefully this technique still works!

Comment: @MarkChackerian solution is right I am using the same.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to make a third `schema.py` file in the same folder as your `settings.py` file.  The new `schema.py` file should look like:

```
import graphene

import first_app.schema as first_app
import second_app.schema as second_app

class Query(first_app.schema.Query, second_app.schema.Query, graphene.ObjectType):
    # Inherits all classes and methods from app-specific queries, so no need
    # to include additional code here.
    pass

class Mutation(first_app.schema.Mutation, second_app.schema.Mutation, graphene.ObjectType):
    # Inherits all classes and methods from app-specific mutations, so no need
    # to include additional code here.
    pass

schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query, mutation=Mutation)
```

Your `settings.py` file should then reference the new third `schema.py` file:

```
GRAPHENE = {
    'SCHEMA': 'parent_folder.schema.schema'
}
```